# ¿Cómo ejemplificar la catarsis?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

La R.A.E. expone como definición de *[catarsis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7v4biYD)* lo siguiente:

> **1**. f. Entre los antiguos griegos, purificación ritual de personas o cosas afectadas de alguna impureza.
>
> **2**. f. Efecto purificador y liberador que causa la tragedia en los espectadores suscitando la compasión, el horror y otras emociones.
>
> **3**. f. Purificación, liberación o transformación interior suscitadas por una experiencia vital profunda.
>
> **4**. f. *Biol*. Expulsión espontánea o provocada de sustancias nocivas al organismo.

Lo he leído varias veces y no me queda completamente claro el concepto. ¿Alguien me podría dar algunos ejemplos a modo de resolver mi duda?

Comment: El uso que reconozco en el día a día es el de la tercera acepción. Los otros son más técnicos.

Comment: Hay una pequeña descripción de catarsis en la literatura, en la página siguiente: https://www.papelenblanco.com/diccionario-literario/diccionario-literario-catarsis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las mejores formas de buscar ejemplos de uso de una palabra es mediante los corpus de referencia. En la web de la RAE tienes el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (textos hasta hace 25 años) y el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) (textos de los últimos 25 años). Buscando en este último la palabra "catarsis" se encuentran [309 casos en 231 documentos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=0&texto=catarsis&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000). Por ejemplo (negritas mías):

> [...] Vizcaíno reflexiona sobre el grave alcance de la extorsión, que ha llegado a la pequeña empresa, y reclama un ejercicio de **catarsis** política a través de unas elecciones que clarifiquen el panorama y lleven a los partidos a anteponer su voluntad de diálogo sobre su capacidad de desencuentro. <sub>(Acepción 3.)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Braudel escribió que el fútbol ocupa el mismo espacio y tiene la misma función que la tragedia entre los griegos, es decir, provoca la **catarsis**. Esta combustión interna de sentimientos en el estadio purifica y regenera y uno acaba saliendo del campo limpio, nuevo y casi feliz. <sub>(Acepción 2.)</sub>

Si lo ves más claro, [sinónimos aceptados](http://www.sinonimos.com/sinonimo.php?palabra=catarsis&x=0&y=0) de "catarsis" son "purga" y "limpieza".